# How to highlight menu item dynamicaly on each page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page header.html which i'm using as a header to every webpage. I have menu items in the header. I want to highlight the current webpage menu dynamically using javascript/jquery. Can any one help me?

**HTML**:

```
<ul class="navigation">
<li class="highlight"><a href="index.html" class="highlight">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="subnet.html">IP Discovery and Password Management</a></li>
<li><a href="test_management.html">Test Management</a></li>
<li><a href="test_dut.cgi">DUT Management</a></li>
<li><a href="test_execmain.cgi">Test Execution</a></li>
<li><a href="result.cgi">Results</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: what server side language are you using? or are you using ajax? How are you implementing the header in each page? This is quite important information...

Comment: @KristofFeys I'm using html have some perl integration. I'm calling this page to every other page. & Not using ajax

Answer (score 1):

First find the page using `window.location` and a regex then

```
jQuery(function($){
    var page = window.location.href.match(/[^/]+$/)[0];
    $('.navigation li a[href="' + page + '"]').parent().addBack().addClass('highlight')
})
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        // Get current url
        // Select an a element that has the matching href and apply a class of 'active'. Also prepend a - to the content of the link
        var url = window.location.href;
        $('.menu a[href="'+url+'"]').addClass('current_page_item');
    });
</script>
```

Reference: http://www.paulund.co.uk/use-jquery-to-highlight-active-menu-item